# Exception on XMLDocument.LoadXml only for specific iso characters

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, windows-runtime

I am using [`Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/el-gr/library/windows/apps/br206173) to parse an xml string.

The code is simple

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

The problem is that it throws an exception when it encounters some specific characters. An example is below. (Yes the XML I am parsing is actually html but it has to be parsed as XML)

This string throws the exception

```
<div>So schnell. So vielf&auml;ltig. Soo lecker!</div>
```

These do not

```
<div>So schnell. So vielfltig. Soo lecker!</div>

<div>So schnell. So vielf&lt;ltig. Soo lecker!</div>
```

These are the message and type of the exception.
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CE002  System.Exception

I don't know why only specific characters trigger the exception. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xml does not support all html characters and the character you mentioned is an html character. Supported character list for xml and html :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Xml only supports  `quot amp apos lt gt`
You will have to use hex value of the other special characters in order for them to be loaded as xml.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have pinpointed the source of the exception. I'd like to offer another solution to using the hex values. One can use the `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode` method to decode the string before parsing it. I will accept your answer in a couple of days (as is the custom)